# Multiple Independent Levels of Security vs Multilevel security

Tags: network, operating-systems

I am looking for a way to isolate two different networks from each other. Suppose we have 2 different networks (public and private). I am looking for a way to connect to these two networks via a single network wire in a trusted way.

I did some search and I found that there are two solutions for this purpose:

1. [Multilevel security (MLS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilevel_security)
2. [Multiple Independent Levels of Security (MILS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_Independent_Levels_of_Security)

Unfortunately, I could not find any obvious difference between these two methods. I also found out that MILS used separation kernel for making different networks independent.

Would you please explain these two methods and their differences for me? Also would you please tell me what is the relation between cross-domain solutions, trusted-OS and these two methods?

Comment: MLS and MILS are not solutions to connect and secure *networks*.

Comment: For starters, make sure that those services in private network listen only on local interface.

Answer (score 0):

MLS and MILS are general concepts rather than technical solutions.

Usually 2 networks are connected with a router inbetween. The router has ACLs or firewall features which allow you to filter the traffic between both networks.